# Elasticsearch:how to change cluster health from yellow to green

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster with one node (by local). Health cluster is yellow. Now I add more one node, but shards can not be allocated in second node. So the health of my cluster is still yellow. I can not change this state to green, not like as this guide:[health cluster example](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_add_an_index.html).

So how to change health state to green?

My cluster:[image]
Cluster health:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'  
{
 "cluster_name" : "astrung",
 "status" : "yellow",
 "timed_out" : false,
 "number_of_nodes" : 2,
 "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
 "active_primary_shards" : 22,
 "active_shards" : 22,
 "relocating_shards" : 0,
 "initializing_shards" : 2,
 "unassigned_shards" : 20
}
```

Shard status:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v'
 index          shard prirep state        docs  store ip          node 
 _river         0     p      STARTED         2  8.1kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 _river         0     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 megacorp       4     p      STARTED         1  3.4kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 megacorp       4     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 megacorp       0     p      STARTED         2  6.1kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 megacorp       0     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 megacorp       3     p      STARTED         1  2.2kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 megacorp       3     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 megacorp       1     p      STARTED         0   115b 192.168.1.3 One  
 megacorp       1     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 megacorp       2     p      STARTED         1  2.2kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 megacorp       2     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 mybucket       2     p      STARTED         1  2.1kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 mybucket       2     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 mybucket       0     p      STARTED         0   115b 192.168.1.3 One  
 mybucket       0     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 mybucket       3     p      STARTED         2  5.4kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 mybucket       3     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 mybucket       1     p      STARTED         1  2.2kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 mybucket       1     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 mybucket       4     p      STARTED         1  2.5kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 mybucket       4     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 .kibana        0     r      INITIALIZING             192.168.1.3 Two  
 .kibana        0     p      STARTED         2  8.9kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 .marvel-kibana 2     p      STARTED         0   115b 192.168.1.3 One  
 .marvel-kibana 2     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 .marvel-kibana 0     r      INITIALIZING             192.168.1.3 Two  
 .marvel-kibana 0     p      STARTED         1  2.9kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 .marvel-kibana 3     p      STARTED         0   115b 192.168.1.3 One  
 .marvel-kibana 3     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 .marvel-kibana 1     p      STARTED         0   115b 192.168.1.3 One  
 .marvel-kibana 1     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 .marvel-kibana 4     p      STARTED         0   115b 192.168.1.3 One  
 .marvel-kibana 4     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 user_ids       4     p      STARTED        11    5kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 user_ids       4     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 user_ids       0     p      STARTED         7 25.1kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 user_ids       0     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 user_ids       3     p      STARTED        11  4.9kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 user_ids       3     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 user_ids       1     p      STARTED         8 28.7kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 user_ids       1     r      UNASSIGNED                                
 user_ids       2     p      STARTED        11  8.5kb 192.168.1.3 One  
 user_ids       2     r      UNASSIGNED
```

Comment: If you have a large amount (e.g. gigabytes) of data then moving shards around can take a long time (e.g. hours). can you update your question with your cluster status - `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'` and list of shards - `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v'`

Comment: "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 22,
  "active_shards" : 22,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 2,
  "unassigned_shards" : 20
}

Comment: so how to move unassigned_shards??is this reason for cluster health?

Comment: Can you run both the commands I posted above and update your question with the results?  if your shards are initialising then its likely they are moving data around - this is a slow process if you have a large amount of data.

Comment: Edit question.I hope u will read this result:))

Comment: it looks like your second node is stuck processing shards - what do the log files say on your second node?  Is it able to write to the data directory?

Comment: action.admin.cluster.state:no known master node, scheduling a retry-action.admin.cluster.health:no known master node, scheduling a retry-action.admin.cluster.state:observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]-action.admin.cluster.health:timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]

Comment: failed to connect to master [[One][wZCJ__NVRze_PNnXaica-g][ubuntu][inet[/192.168.1.2:9300]]], retrying...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [One][inet[/192.168.1.2:9300]] connect_timeout[30s]

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.1.2:9300-(192.168.1.2 is my master)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I suggest updating the replication factor of all the indices to 0 and then update it back to 1.

Here's a curl to get you started

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_settings' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}'
```

Comment: Getting stuck in yellow status seems to happen randomly even for small datasets. Seems like a bug in Elasticsearch. This answer solved it for me.

Comment: @mohitt - ES all of sudden stopped working for us. setting to 0 & 1 doesn't resolve this issue for me. One of the index is in yellow status. "unassigned_shards" : 3 index                                                         shard prirep state      node unassigned.reason
es1_secure                                                    3     r      UNASSIGNED      REPLICA_ADDED
.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-202xxxxxx 0     r      UNASSIGNED      NODE_LEFT
.monitoring-es-7-2xxxxxx                                   0     r      UNASSIGNED      REPLICA_ADDED

Answer (score 5):

like @mohitt said above, update `number_of_replicas` to zero(for local dev only,be careful to use in production)

you can run the below in Kibana DevTool Console:

```
PUT _settings
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}
```

Comment: ES all of sudden stopped working for us. setting to 0 & 1 doesn't resolve this issue for me. One of the index is in yellow status. "unassigned_shards" : 3 index shard prirep state node unassigned.reason es1_secure 3 r UNASSIGNED REPLICA_ADDED .ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-202xxxxxx 0 r UNASSIGNED NODE_LEFT .monitoring-es-7-2xxxxxx 0 r UNASSIGNED REPLICA_ADDED

Answer (score 1):

thou recovery normally takes a long time, looking at the number and size of your documents, it should take a very sort time to recover.

Looks like you have issues with the nodes contacting each other, check firewall rules, ensure ports 9200 and 9300 are reachable from each.